# How to extract the frame rate of a source clip of a movie strip?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

I know the width and height of a source clip can be extracted with this: https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.SequenceElement.html

Ex.:

```
bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip.elements[0].orig_width
bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip.elements[0].orig_height
```

But how do I get the fps of the source clip?